# monetdb: Online Schema Alters

Tags: monetdb

Does MonetDB support online schema changes? For example adding/changing a column on the fly while the tables are loaded in memory. Many in-memory databases have to restarted to get the schema changes reflected. So, I was wondering if MonetDB took care of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. MonetDB supports SQL-99 which includes DDL statements (that are immediately reflected in the schema).

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I have also tested this. The online updates are seamless